# Android Location Manager crashing the app when called

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I wrote a code to get the current position of the device every time the user clicks on a button. But when I call the listener, the app just crashes. Can anyone give me an insight of what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
public void onStartService() 
{
    addListenerLocation();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void addListenerLocation() 
{
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener()
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            currentLat = location.getLatitude();
            InstanciaObjetos.setPEDLAT(currentLat);
            currentLon = location.getLongitude();
            InstanciaObjetos.setPEDLON(currentLon);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {
            //TODO -- Barney says what should happen
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {
            Location lastKnownLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(lastKnownLocation!=null)
            {
                currentLat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                currentLon = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
            }

        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {

        }
    };
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
}
```

to start the service I just call onStartService(). Is there anything else I need to do?

I've just attached the logcat. Now I realized what needs to be done (I guess).

```
09-21 23:17:41.209 8861-8861/br.com.appvendasfs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.appvendasfs, PID: 8861
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5253)
  at appVendasFS.DAO.PedidosDAO.addListenerLocation(PedidosDAO.java:47)
  at appVendasFS.DAO.PedidosDAO.onStartService(PedidosDAO.java:40)
  at appVendasFS.DAO.PedidosDAO.Inserir(PedidosDAO.java:97)
  at appVendasFS.UI.TelaVenda.Inserir_Pedido(TelaVenda.java:813)
  at appVendasFS.UI.TelaVenda.onClick_botao(TelaVenda.java:593)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: pls add the crash report

Comment: http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/94/94eb289f247f6e711a9975bed6783d1db4a15af4a9f2b7cd8f1a560a3bfb540a.jpg ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `addListenerLocation();` in the service's `onCreate()` method instead.

Comment: I have called it on 'onCreate()' method and it worked. Thank you, sir.